# pack individual .jpg image files into RecordIO (.rec) files

Tags: python, r, jpeg, mxnet

I'm trying to go through the MXNET tutorial (https://statist-bhfz.github.io/cats_dogs_finetune), but have trouble making the RecordIO ".rec" files used to process the pictures.

I have tried the suggested approach:
python C:/mxnet-20170203/tools/im2rec.py --list=1 --recursive=1 --train-ratio=0.8 cats_dogs train_pad_224x224

python C:/mxnet-20170203/tools/im2rec.py --num-thread=4 --pass-through=1 cats_dogs_train.lst train_pad_224x224

python C:/mxnet-20170203/tools/im2rec.py --num-thread=4 --pass-through=1 cats_dogs_val.lst train_pad_224x224

But i get the error: "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MXIndexedRecordIO'"
when doing so.

Is there a way to generate the ".rec" files in R directly? And if not, how do i get pass the error?

Thanks.

Kr,

Daniel

Comment: I don't think there is an R version of imtorec. I just tested im2rec.py and it seems to work fine (https://gist.github.com/indhub/a2db93daed908d62a736b5e951639763).

Which version of MXNet are you using? If built from source, can you let me know the commit hash (git rev-parse HEAD)?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting seems related to the fact that you are trying to use a newer version of im2rec.py than the one that came with your installed version of mxnet, hence the missing modules.

try using the `im2rec.py` script located in your own mxnet installation folder, somewhere like this `python2.7/site-packages/mxnet/tools/im2rec.py`

Also note that if you upgrade your version of mxnet, the syntax of im2rec has changed to:

`im2rec.py --list --recursive --train-ratio=0.8 cats_dogs train_pad_224x224`